# EditText check if input is from 0 to 9 and display toast?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

The program should display the second toast "Please introduce a real letter" in the case of an input number from 0 to 9.

The only thing that worked was this code:

```
if(letter.equals("0")) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Please introduce a real letter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But I could only set it up for one letter.

This is the full code:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLetter);
String letter = myEditText.getText().toString();

if(letter.length() == 1) {
  checkLetter(letter);
}

if( ) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Please introduce a real letter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Please introduce a letter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: when you get this finished, put it on Code Review. It was one of the best experiences I've ever had.

Comment: The code above does not compile, due to a trailing bracket. Also, your `if` clause is empty, meaning only one block will ever be executed (there is not actually a branch there).

Comment: Yes, I know. The code was not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(letter);
    if (number > 9 || number < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Number should be from 0 to 9",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
    }

    // number is correct, work with your number here    

} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to convert the string to number: " + letter,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the method `Character.isDigit();`

```
char letter = input.charAt(0);
if(Character.isDigit(letter))
{
    //good input
}
else
{
    //bad input
}
```

If however you are looking to validate a number, not just 0-9, use `Integer.parseInt(input)`.

Comment: also add checking for bounds `[0..9]`

Comment: How can a character be a digit and not be `[0..9]`

Comment: sorry, my bad. Friday evening :) have my +1

Comment: actually this is possible, check the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    try{
        int x = Integer.parseInt(letter);

        if(x < 10 && x >= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please introduce a real letter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please introduce a letter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        //Not a number
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println` is not a suitable method in this case. Use `Toast` instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

modified from James Wierzba above, because isDigit could actually be wrong

```
char letter = input.charAt(0);
if(letter >= '0' && letter <= '9')
{
    //good input
}
else
{
    //bad input
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29

> Determines if the specified character (Unicode code point) is a digit.
>
> A character is a digit if its general category type, provided by
>   getType(codePoint), is DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER.
>
> Some Unicode character ranges that contain digits:
>
> ```
> '\u0030' through '\u0039', ISO-LATIN-1 digits ('0' through '9')
> '\u0660' through '\u0669', Arabic-Indic digits
> '\u06F0' through '\u06F9', Extended Arabic-Indic digits
> '\u0966' through '\u096F', Devanagari digits
> '\uFF10' through '\uFF19', Fullwidth digits
> ```